# require slim error into my index.php

Tags: angularjs, slim

require slim error into my index.php

Warning: require(/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project_angular_routing\slim_project_angular_routing\index.php on line 4

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3XPJ.png)         [resultss in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MykMq.png)

Comment: Refere: http://mrbool.com/slim-framework-introducing-a-new-php-concept/32328

Comment: Acording to your architecture, I think that the import should be `./slim` instead of `../slim`. Because is in the same folder as index.php (if the index.php that is open is the on in /slim/slim/index.php, as it seems). If no, you should catch the relative path between index and slim/index (or autoload).

Comment: thks verry much, know its work correctly, i had to reinstall slim 2*  an i follow the procedure  mention  in the link you provided (Refered)